# get element by id - using variable

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I'm trying to use the function `getElementById()`.

I have several ID's that i want to change style of, one by one, in an increasing order. I have a variable called `numberOfTimes`, which increases with 1 every time.

The names of the ID's are 1, 2, 3, 4 etc, and up to 8.

Is there some way I can use the variable-name in the function - if not, how should you solve this?

```
var numberOfTimes = 1;
document.getElementById(1).style.backgroundColor = "green";
```

Comment: How about `for-loop` ?

Comment: How about don't use an ID but a class. Then you can target the index of the class instead.

Comment: @JoshLeeDucks, OP might be after an sort-of-a animation although I don't see any `setTimeout()` here.

Comment: He can achieve animation even with a classname, no differences

Comment: Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I wasn't so describing in my question, but yes its an animation and a kind of timer I'm building. I'm jumping between several functions between each increase of the number so therefore it feels difficult with a for-loop. But finally it workt to use a variable inside the parantheses, I must have written something wrong before that made the bug. And I've learnt not to use numbers-only as ID-names :) .

Comment: I'm new to JavaScript and I'm writing in Visual Studio now. But it's difficult with the intellisence there... and to debug. Is there some better program to write JavaScript-code in?

Comment: @NiCe, you can use Atom or Sublime Text 3. Both are great options, I personally use Sublime Text 3.

Answer (score 0):

Let's pretend your `IDs` look like this `idx` (x stands for the number). You can do:

```
var numberOfTimes = 8;

for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfTimes; ++i) {
    document.getElementById('id' + i).style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution if you really specific to change the color of the element one by one. Then you can use for loop.

second

```
document.getElementById(1)
```

You can use integer value directly but preferable you should use id with some text.
just use like this in for loop

```
for(var i=1;i<=8;i++){
document.getElementById("div_"+i).style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

Comment: A better recommendation would be not to use purely numerical element IDs. Besides, the int will be implicitly converted to a string anyway (iirc...)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. and i also agreed with you that id in html always with some string value preferable

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I wasn't so describing in my question, but  its an animation and a kind of timer I'm building. I'm jumping between several functions between each increase of the number so therefore it feels difficult with a for-loop. But finally it workt to use a variable inside the parantheses, I must have written something wrong before that made the bug. And I've learnt not to use numbers-only as ID-names :)

Answer (score 0):

Numbers-only ID are not a good practice, I hope this quetion is in the purpose of learning.

```js
for(var i = 1; i < 9; i++){
    document.getElementById(i).style['background'] = 'green';
}
```

```css
div {
  width:100%;
  height:20px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
<div id="5"></div>
<div id="6"></div>
<div id="7"></div>
<div id="8"></div>
```

Comment: `i < 8` will miss element #8, won't it?

Comment: Thank you, yes I'm new to this and it's for the purpose of learning. Now I know that I should avoid numbers-only.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in other answers and comments, it is highly recommended not to use numbers only as IDs, also you can pick these divs upon a unique class name which will get you an array of them, and just loop through the array just like in [*this fiddle*](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/jt40qnc4/3/).

However here's the code [**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/jt40qnc4/2/)

```js
var id = 1;

changeBG();

function changeBG() {
  document.getElementById('el-' + id).style.backgroundColor = "green";
  id++;
  var t = setTimeout(changeBG, 500);
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="el-1"></div>
<div id="el-2"></div>
<div id="el-3"></div>
<div id="el-4"></div>
<div id="el-5"></div>
<div id="el-6"></div>
<div id="el-7"></div>
<div id="el-8"></div>
```

Comment: Why have `id` as a global variable and increment it in the function, rather than using a loop or allowing proper control? What happens if the user calls it too many times and it refers to an invalid element?

Comment: Honestly picking elements by id like that is all wrong, this why I had that prefix before the answer, but it's the OP code, or did you not read the intro of my answer?

Comment: also, "*increment it in the function*" I wanted to use the `setTimeout()`

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I wasn't so describing in my question, but  its an animation and a kind of timer I'm building. I'm jumping between several functions between each increase of the number so therefore it feels difficult with a for-loop. But finally it workt to use a variable inside the parantheses, I must have written something wrong before that made the bug. And I've learnt not to use numbers-only as ID-names :)